# JQuery email form with clear entries button, trying to add * back no error message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an assignment for my JavaScript/Jquery class. I have an email entry form. I need to add an event handler to the Clear Entries button and also add the asterisk back to to the span at the end of the form field.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Join Email List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="email_list.css">

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="email_list.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Please join our email list</h1>
        <form id="email_form" name="email_form" action="join.html" method="get">
            <label for="email_address1">Email Address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="email_address1">
            <span id="email_address1_error">*</span><br>

            <label for="email_address2">Re-enter Email Address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="email_address2">
            <span id="email_address2_error">*</span><br>

            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="first_name">
            <span id="first_name_error">*</span><br>

            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="button" id="join_list" value="Join our List"><br>

            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="button" id="clear_entries" value="Clear Entries">
        </form>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#join_list").click(
        function() {
            var emailAddress1 = $("#email_address1").val();
            var emailAddress2 = $("#email_address2").val();
            var isValid = true;

            // validate the first email address
            if (emailAddress1 == "") { 
                $("#email_address1").next().text("This field is required.");
                isValid = false;
            } else {
                $("#email_address1").next().text("");
            } 

            // validate the second email address
            if (emailAddress2 == "") { 
                $("#email_address2_error").text("This field is required.");
                isValid = false; 
            } else if (emailAddress1 !== emailAddress2) { 
                $("#email_address2").next().text("This entry must equal first entry.");
                isValid = false;
            } else {
                $("#email_address2").next().text("");
            }

            // validate the first name entry  
            if ($("#first_name").val() == "") {
                $("#first_name").next().text("This field is required.");
                isValid = false;
            } 
            else {
                $("#first_name").next().text("");
            }

            // submit the form if all entries are valid
            if (isValid) {
                $("#email_form").submit(); 
            }
        } // end function
    );  // end click

    //on-click event to clear out all text boxes
    $("#clear_entries").click (
        function () {
            $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
                $(this).val(" ");
            });
            $("#email_address1_error").next().text("*"); $("#email_address2_error").next().text("*");$("#first_name_error").next().text("*");

        });

    //
    $("#email_address1").focus();
}); // end ready
```

The instructions say that the adding the asterisk back can be done in one statement.
This is what I used "$("#email_address1_error").next().text("*"); $("#email_address2_error").next().text("*");$("#first_name_error").next().text("*");".
There is no error message to tell me what's wrong, but the asterisk is not showing up, so something about the way I wrote that statement is wrong. How should that be done?

Comment: you are getting error messages when field was empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the error span ids as your selector, then calling next().  Just remove the .next().

ie. change

```
$("#email_address1_error").next().text("*"); $("#email_address2_error").next().text("*");$("#first_name_error").next().text("*");
```

to

```
$("#email_address1_error").text("*"); $("#email_address2_error").text("*");$("#first_name_error").text("*");
```

and voila!

Comment: That was it, THANK YOU!. Still just getting a handle on this. I like Jquery, but there is a lot to learn and I am also taking a Java class with a not so great Java teacher (he might be good at teaching other stuff, but not Java.

Answer (score 0):

you already doing loop every input text, $(this).next().text('*');

```
$("#clear_entries").click (
        function () {
            $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
                $(this).val(" ");
                $(this).next().text('*');
            });

        });
```